# itextsharp PDF table header repeats with an extra first row

Tags: c#, itext

I am using `iTextSharp` library to generate PDF table.

To repeat header (2 rows header) on each page, I am using `HeaderRows` property of PDF table. It repeats the header on each page but, below  the header, it inserts an extra a new blank row with default formatting. This extra row doesn’t impact `Rowspan` values of columns and rows.

How can I remove this extra row from table?

```
IList<Common.rowspan> Row = new List<Common.rowspan>();

for (int i = 0; i < RowsCount; i = i + 5)
{
    Row.Add(new Common.rowspan()
    {
        row = i,
        col = 0,
        span = 5
    });
}

float[] Width = new float[] { 250, 450, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200, 200 };

public PdfPTable GetPdfTable(string Module, DataTable dt, IList<Common.rowspan> row, float[] width, int HeaderRow = 1)
{
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(width.Length);
    PdfPCell cell;      
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(dc.Caption));              
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }   
    int rowindex = 0; int colindex = 0; bool rowskip = false;
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (row[rowindex].row == i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(PageController.DecodeText(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString())));
                    if (row[rowindex].col == j && !rowskip)
                    {
                        cell.Rowspan = row[rowindex].span;
                        rowskip = true;
                        colindex = row[rowindex].col;
                    }                        
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                }
                if (rowindex < row.Count - 1)
                    rowindex = rowindex + 1;
                rowskip = false;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (colindex != j)
                    {
                        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(PageController.DecodeText(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString())));                            
                        table.AddCell(cell);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("No Record Found.", NoRecordFoundBlackBold_Calibri_11));
        cell.Colspan = dt.Columns.Count;
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }
    table.HeaderRows = HeaderRow;
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your part of code, so we can identify the problem.

Comment: Also tell us which version of iTextSharp you're using because there have been numerous changes to the `PdfPTable` functionality. A problem that exists in one version may not exist in another one.

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered same issue. In my case it happens when last row does not fit on page and Itextsharp splits it.

The extra row at the beginning of the page is just second part of last previous page row which was split.

Solved by setting table properties SplitLate = true and SplitRows = false

```
    private static PdfPTable CreateTable(PdfTableArgument tableArg)
    {

        PdfPTable result = CreateTableWithColumns(tableArg);
        // skip initialization code

        result.SplitLate = true;
        result.SplitRows = false;

        return result;
    }
```